# Deleting all file asynchronsly from amazon S3 bucket

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core

I want to delete all the files from a particular S3 bucket. The files exist in a folder called "test" inside S3 bucket.  I couldn't figure out how to delete all the files inside the S3 bucket in a loop. I am not sure what parameters can I pass to DeleteObjectsAsync in order to delete the files. This is what I have so far after reading some online AWS documents:

```
using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(_configuration["AwsAccesKey"].ToString(), _configuration["AwsSecretKey"].ToString()))
            {
                var request = new ListObjectsRequest
                {
                    
                    BucketName = _configuration["AwsBucketName"].ToString()
                };
                
                var response = await client.ListObjectsAsync(request);

                foreach (var entry in response.S3Objects)
                {
                    await client.DeleteObjectsAsync(request, entry.Key);
                }
            }
            return View();
```

User has been asking me to delete all the files whenever they click the button on the front end.This is not dependent on duration.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a lifecycle action? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3PutLifecycleConfigurationPutLifecycleConfigurationRequest.html

Comment: This is more for deleting files at certain period of time

Comment: @Anjali It would be more helpful if your question explained what you are _actually_ trying to do, so that we can offer appropriate advice. If you want to "delete files at certain periods of time", please update your question to reflect this fact, together with details of exactly what you are wanting to accomplish. You will then receive more appropriate responses.

Comment: The line `await client.DeleteObjectsAsync(request, entry.Key);` is referring to `request`, which seems to be a `ListObjectsRequest`? It should actually be creating a [`DeleteObjectsRequest`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TDeleteObjectsRequest.html) that can contain a list of multiple objects to delete. Your code should populate this list (eg by using `AddKey()`) within the `for` loop, and then it should call `DeleteObjectsAsync()` at the very end once the list is populated with all objects to delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **DeleteObjectsAsync** method excepts **DeleteObjectsRequest** which should contain all the keys to objects you want to delete.

Your code should be something like this:

```
var request = new ListObjectsRequest
{
    BucketName = "bucketname"
};

var response = await client.ListObjectsAsync(request);
var keys = new List<KeyVersion>();
foreach (var item in response.S3Objects)
{
    // Here you can provide VersionId as well.
    keys.Add(new KeyVersion { Key = item.Key });
}

var multiObjectDeleteRequest = new DeleteObjectsRequest()
{
    BucketName = "bucketname",
    Objects = keys
};

var deleteObjectsResponse = await client.DeleteObjectsAsync(multiObjectDeleteRequest);
```

It's important to note that the ListObjectsAsync returns at most 1000 objects. DeleteObjectsRequest deletes at most 1000 objects.

You can read more here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/delete-multiple-objects.html

Comment: Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Below is the entire code to recursively delete all the files in a particular S3 bucket:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteAll()
        {
            using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(_configuration["AwsAccesKey"].ToString(), _configuration["AwsSecretKey"].ToString()))
            {
                var request = new ListObjectsRequest
                {
                    BucketName = _configuration["AwsBucketName"].ToString()
                };
                var response = await client.ListObjectsAsync(request);
                foreach (var entry in response.S3Objects)
                {
                    await client.DeleteObjectAsync(_configuration["AwsBucketName"].ToString(), entry.Key);

                }
            }
                
            return View();

        }
```